# JQuery Mobile init toggle after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, function, jquery-mobile, init

This is a new version of my previous question which has been answered.
The ultimate solution to the problem has actually not been found.

I didn't knew in my last question what was causing the problem.
Now I know what it is.

The testcase:

- HTML
- CSS
- JQuery Mobile
- Simple button when clicked opens a menu
- When clicked on a link in the menu the desired page loads
- Display the item on screen and allow the user to click the page again

The issue is:
When the next page has been loaded through an AJAX call the code :

```
                    $( "#TestMenu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {});
```

Stops working.
This should be solvable by reinitializing the function. HOWEVER I have no clue how to do this...

See the below code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <title>Test &amp; Go</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1080, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
        <link href="interface/test/mobile.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function TestAndGoFunctions(){
                $("body").on("click", "#TestMenuButton", function() {
                    ///######## TOGGLE THE DISPLAY STATE OF THE MENU
                    $( "#TestMenu" ).toggle( "slow", function() {});
                });
            }
            $(document).on('pageinit',function(){
                TestAndGoFunctions();
            });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="TestMenuButton"></div>
            <div id="TestMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="?page=start">Start</a></li>
                    <li><a href="?page=actions">Actions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div id="testBlock">
            VARIABLE = <?php echo @$_GET['page']; ?>
            <div onclick="TestClick();">CLICK</div>
            <ul style="background-color: blue; color: white;">
                <li><a href="?page=start">Start</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page=actions">Actions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope that someone would know what the problem is.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using unique IDs across pages?

Comment: Yes I do use unique ID's. :-o